# Convert ISO to IMG using terminal

Tags: command-line, iso

How do I convert an .ISO on my desktop to .IMG using the terminal on Ubuntu?

I have minimal knowledge of running commands in using the Terminal.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Add this information to your question. Also add more context.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. I found a work around now. I also had a DMG as well as an ISO and I converted to DMG to a IMG using dmg2img in the terminal.